# ScalaTest - How to verify a collection contains a sub class

Tags: scala, scalatest

With ScalaTest, it's straightforward enough to test that an object is of a particular class with something like:

```
myPet shouldBe a [Dog]
```

But what I would like to do is verify that a collection of some base type has at least one of a particular sub type.  I imagine the syntax could look something like this but it doesn't work:

```
myPets should contain a [Cat]
```

I can achieve the same result with 'exists' and 'shouldBe true' but it's not quite as expressive.

```
myPets.exists(_.isInstanceOf[Cat]) shouldBe true
```

Is this what I have to do or is there a feature of ScalaTest that I'm not aware of?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`atLeast(1, myPets) shouldBe a [Cat]` should work, I believe (can't test at the moment, based just on an example from http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#inspectorShorthands).